Error: cgroup support missing memory features in running kernel
Im using Ubuntu 24.04 and im trying to setup DOMjudge. While setting up the judgehost froom this link im getting the following error
Error: cgroup support missing memory features in running kernel. Unable to continue.
To fix this, please make the following changes:
1. In /etc/default/grub, add 'cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1' to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT.
On modern distros (e.g. Debian bullseye and Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish) which have cgroup v2 enabled by default,
you need to add 'systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0' as well.
2. Run update-grub
3. Reboot
here is the output of cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic root=UUID=0df047a9-dd1e-4d30-a9f0-dfce8fbc340c ro cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0
and here is the output of sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
I have tried editing the /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
and then apply sudo update-grub and then sudo reboot several times. Still no progress.

i have the same problem so will follow this. i also added the same line on ubuntu 24.04 on two places in grub file
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="swapaccount=1 cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="swapaccount=1 cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"


didn't work. still the same error.
